# PHP array loop - unable to access elements

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, curly-braces

I have an array.
It comes from this query:

```
$table_array=array();
$table_array = $mydb->get_results($mydb->prepare("SELECT sid, stitle FROM tablename"));
```

I successfully retrieve the data. The console shows the json_encode returns via ajax (success function):

```
function align_surveys(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "align_sids"},
        success:
            function(data){
                console.log('data: '+ data)
                }             
        }); 
}

"data:":[{"sid":"525331","stitle":"First Title"},{"sid":"367775","stitle":"Second Title"}]
```

However, when I run a foreach loop, I get a 500 error when I try to access it's elements.

This errors:

```
foreach($table_array as $row){
  $s_ids[] = $row[0];
}
```

And, this errors:

```
foreach($table_array as $row){
  $s_ids[] = $row['sid'];
}
```

**gettype** tells me this is in fact an array. But, anytime I reference the array element, I error out. I cannot solve it. Is it something to do with extra curly braces inside the square brackets? Anyone, please, point me in the right direction. Been hours....

**UPDATE:**
print_r show me this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [surveyls_survey_id] => 525331 [0] => 525331 [surveyls_title] => New Survey [1] => New Survey ) [1] => Array ( [surveyls_survey_id] => 367775 [0] => 367775 [surveyls_title] => Second Survey [1] => Second Survey ) )
```

This looks to me like it's an array of arrays where the keys are actually the values...Not sure how or why this is the result I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I had to json_encode the array so that I could parse it effectively.
Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

That "data" at the beginning looks like it's apart of another object. Try `table_array['data']` and see if that works for you. If not, can you post the entire json object that is outputted by json_encode.

Comment: That "data:" is just part of the console.log statement - to help me keep things straight.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons you might have this issue.

The first appears to be addressed where you've explicitly set the type to array();
The second is with the JSON_DECODE command.  If you use the boolean true/false with that function, it can return an array or an object.

$mayarray = json_decode($jsonobject,true);

This loads the JSON data into an associative array.  If you use false or if you leave it blank, depending on your PHP config, it will return as an object, which means if you attempt to access it as if it were an array, you will get a 500 error.